# PHP function is having problems with content passed with HTMl tags

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In my theme's functions.php file I have a string that generates surrounding HTML and gets content through the `get_the_content()` function

The issue is that if the content being passed through that function has html tags, it breaks it and puts the content into a div of its own.

So if the content being passed in is straight text like 'this is text' then it will generate like

```
<div class='col-md-4 my-2'>
    <div class='coupon-container shadow' style='background: url(". $thumbnail . "); background-size:cover; background-position:center;'> 
        <div class='coupon-content'>
            <p class='coupon-title font-weight-bold'>Title</p>
            <p class='coupon-desc' id='coupon-description'>This is text</p>
            <a class='coupon-link' href=". get_the_permalink() .">Open in new tab</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if the content is passed in as `<p>this is <a>text</a></p>` then it will generate with the content under the content section instead of within it, like so:

```
<div class='col-md-4 my-2'>
    <div class='coupon-container shadow' style='background: url(". $thumbnail . "); background-size:cover; background-position:center;'>
        <div class='coupon-content'>
            <p class='coupon-title font-weight-bold'>Title</p>
            <p class='coupon-desc' id='coupon-description'></p>
            <p>this is <a>text</a></p>
            <a class='coupon-link' href=". get_the_permalink() .">Open in new tab</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it so that even content passed in with existing html tags gets put into the coupon-desc section?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code in question. Currently, I see not PHP code in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways:

**Get rid of `<p></p>` or raplace with block elements**

Paragraph elements CANNOT be nested, and browsers will assume you are trying to make a new paragraph. However, you can use elements such as div, to keep the contents in HTML, but still apply styling and such to the div.

**Pass it through PHP function to get rid of all HTML**

Pass the data through [wp_strip_all_tags()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/), which will remobe ALL HTML tags and just return pure text string.

Comment: Great call, I changed the class from <p> to <div> and it looks like that fixed it! I totally overlooked the ability to nest paragraph tags, thank you for your help!